# Efficient way for creating mapping

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables as below

`CITY_A`

| ID | CODE | CITY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 90 | PARIS |
| 002 | 90 | PARIS |
| 003 | 85 | PARIS |
| 004 | 60 | SYDNEY |
| 005 | 75 | SYDNEY |
| 006 | 75 | SYDNEY |

`CITY_B`

| ID | CODE | CITY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | IN | PA |
| 002 | OUT | PA |
| 003 | OUT | PA |
| 004 | IN | SYD |
| 005 | OUT | SYD |
| 006 | IN | SYD |

The content is same in both tables but the representation is different. I have 2 mapping here for `CITY` column and `CODE` column.

Mapping for `CITY_A`

| CODE | CITY | MEANING |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 90 | PARIS | ACTIVE |
| 85 | PARIS | NOT_ACTIVE |
| 60 | SYDNEY | ACTIVE |
| 75 | SYDNEY | NOT_ACTIVE |

Mapping for `CITY_B`

| CODE | CITY | MEANING |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IN | PA | ACTIVE |
| OUT | PA | NOT_ACTIVE |
| IN | SYD | ACTIVE |
| OUT | SYD | NOT_ACTIVE |

Now i have to compare both tables based on the mapping and find the mismatches. So my expected output is

| ID | CITY | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | PARIS | MATCH |
| 002 | PARIS | MISMATCH |
| 003 | PARIS | MATCH |
| 004 | SYDNEY | MATCH |
| 005 | SYDNEY | MATCH |
| 006 | SYDNEY | MISMATCH |

Currently I'm using `CASE` with Temp table. It is too big.

```
SELECT A.ID , CASE WHEN A.CODE = 90 AND A.CITY = 'PARIS' THEN 'ACTIVE' 
                   WHEN A.CODE = 85 AND A.CITY = 'PARIS' THEN 'NOT_ACTIVE' 
               -- FOR OTHER CITIES
               END AS A.CODE_MEANING,
               CITY
INTO #TEMP_CITY_A              
FROM CITY_A A

SELECT B.ID,CASE WHEN B.CODE = 'IN'  AND B.CITY='PA' THEN 'ACTIVE'
                   WHEN B.CODE = 'OUT'  AND B.CITY='PA' THEN 'NOT_ACTIVE' 
              -- FOR OTHER CITIES
            END AS B.CODE_MEANING,
            CASE WHEN B.CITY = 'PA' THEN 'PARIS' 
                 WHEN B.CITY = 'SYD' THEN 'SYDNEY'
             -- FOR OTHER CITIES
            END AS CITY
 INTO #TEMP_CITY_B              
 FROM CITY_B B

SELECT A.ID ,A.CITY, 
     CASE WHEN A.CODE_MEANING!=B.CODE_MEANING THEN 'MISMATCH' ELSE 'MATCH' END AS RESULT
FROM #TEMP_CITY_A A
JOIN #TEMP_CITY_B B ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.CITY = B.CITY
```

Which is the most efficient way?

Comment: Why don't you just `JOIN` `CITY_A` with `Mapping for CITY_A` rather than hardcode the value

Comment: then create one or use `VALUE` Constructor

Comment: There is no `Mapping for CITY_A` table yet :) @Squirrel. Should I create a table for mapping separately then? Actually I don't have permission to create table. If that is the best way then I will request for it. Only problem is that It will take so much of time for all the approvals

Comment: if the mapping table is huge with lots of rows, it is best to create as a table. If it is just few rows, you can use a `CTE` or `VALUE` Constructor

Comment: Not so huge. I have around 25 rows. Can you please show an example with `VALUE`? @Squirrel

Comment: Table Value Constructor https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/283696/how-to-create-a-mapping-table

Comment: Table Value Constructor example ```CREATE TABLE #MAP_CITY_A (CODE TINYINT, CITY VARCHAR(10), MEANING VARCHAR(10))
INSERT #MAP_CITY_A (CODE,CITY,MEANING)
VALUES (90, 'Paris', 'Active'),(85, 'Paris', 'Not_Active'),(60, 'Sydney', 'Active'),(75, 'Sydney', 'Not_Active')```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible way to achieve your desired result using CTEs with table value constructors for the mapping tables:

```sql
WITH CITY_A_MAP AS (
  SELECT * FROM (
    VALUES(90, 'PARIS', 'Active'),(85, 'PARIS', 'Not_Active'),(60, 'SYDNEY', 'Active'),(75, 'SYDNEY', 'Not_Active')
  ) AS MAP(CODE, CITY, MEANING)
),
CITY_B_MAP AS (
  SELECT * FROM (
    VALUES ('IN', 'PA', 'Active'),('OUT', 'PA', 'Not_Active'),('IN', 'SYD', 'Active'),('OUT', 'SYD', 'Not_Active')
  ) AS MAP(CODE, CITY, MEANING)
)
SELECT A.ID, A.CITY,
       CASE WHEN MA.MEANING = MB.MEANING THEN 'MATCH' ELSE 'MISMATCH' END AS RESULT
FROM CITY_A A
JOIN CITY_A_MAP MA ON MA.CITY = A.CITY AND MA.CODE = A.CODE
JOIN CITY_B B ON B.ID = A.ID
JOIN CITY_B_MAP MB ON MB.CITY = B.CITY AND MB.CODE = B.CODE
ORDER BY A.ID
```

Output:

```
ID  CITY    RESULT
1   PARIS   MATCH
2   PARIS   MISMATCH
3   PARIS   MATCH
4   SYDNEY  MATCH
5   SYDNEY  MATCH
6   SYDNEY  MISMATCH
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a79e62fbb19b3230d28ea1de035f7c1b)